# How to make an image fit in an imageButton in android?

Tags: android

I need to make four `imageButton`s in my app. Whenever I insert a JPEG image into Android Studio and put it on the `imageButton`, the button just grows in size so that the image doesn't fit on the button.

I need the button to just stay the same size that I've made it and need the image to fit nicely and be centered on the button. I've tried everything. Does anyone know how to do this? Can this be done with any sized image of any format?

Comment: what is the height and width of the button are they wrap_content or did you specify any height and width

Comment: try to use scaleType attribute in xml layout to any fitXY or fitcneter.

Comment: I have four image buttons total, 2 buttons in two rows and when I insert the image into the bottom buttons using fixXY, they work just fine. But the problem is with the two top buttons, when I insert the images into those, then the button and the image gets stretched across the screen to the bottom covering up the buttons I have at the bottom and even with fitXY, it doesn't work, so does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To make your image fill `ImageButton` then use - `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/TextButton"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/jpeg_image" />
```

Comment: I have four image buttons total, 2 buttons in two rows and when I insert the image into the bottom buttons using fixXY, they work just fine. But the problem is with the two top buttons, when I insert the images into those, then the button and the image gets stretched across the screen to the bottom covering up the buttons I have at the bottom and even with fitXY, it doesn't work, so does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: change your RelativeLayout to horizontal (at your ImageButton row) and if it doesn't work remove android:layout_weight="0.5" attribute or post your code here so i can understand and solve your problem